Fat guy in electric wheelchair
I watched this movie couple years ago, I think it's from 2005 or newer. It should be a Hollywood movie, and it's set in the future. I remember, the people were lazy, hooked up on virtual reality and had big screen TVs all over their walls. There was this fat guy and i think he was watching porn when the special police kicked the wall and startled him. He tried to flee on his electric wheelchair and that was pretty funny to my friend and me.

Fat people in wheelchairs in the future made me think of Wall-E. But I don't think that's it. :P

Wall-E is great movie, but unfortunately it's not it. @TrishLing

Hence the smiley. :)

Ha!  That was actually the first thing that popped into my head until the word "porn" was mentioned.  :oP

Hahaha! I'll remember that and try to avoid it in future :D @JohnnyBones

Maybe The Gamer (2009)? 

In 2024, inventor and professional computer programmer, Ken Castle
  (Michael C. Hall), has revolutionized the gaming industry with his
  self-replicating nanites that replace brain cells and allow full
  control of all motor functions by a third party. Castle's first
  application of this technology is a game called Society, which allows
  gamers to control a real person in a pseudo community (much like The
  Sims or Second Life). This allows players to engage in all manner of
  debauchery, such as deliberately injuring their "characters" and
  engaging in rough sex with random people. As a result, those who work
  as "characters" in Society are paid very well in compensation.

One of the characters is a morbidly obese gamer named Gorge, as seen in this clip:




I agree... Gamer ... staring Gerard Butler. The scene is about half way through the movie.
